# Operate on Cached data per node

Tags: ignite

I'm able to do affinity computer-data collocation with apache ignite.  In the following two examples, it works as expected.

```
    // Works on all nodes
    IgniteUtil.getIgnite().compute().broadcast(() -> {
        System.out.println("Should happen on all nodes");
        cache.get(key).forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println(x);
        });
    });

    // Works on just the one node
    IgniteUtil.getIgnite().compute().affinityRun(IgniteUtil.CACHE_NAME, key , () -> {
        System.out.println("Should only happen on one node");
        cache.get(key).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
    });
```

However, I want to run a lambda against all the nodes data.  So for example, say I had cached For every person, all of their orders from Amazon.  I want to know what the total dollar amount is for everyone's orders.

I'm probably just missing an example, but according to the docs I don't see how to do this.  In the examples I've seen I have to specify the keys I want to compute with.  In this example, I just want to be able to do some lambda on all of the nodes, with each node only operating on its own share of the data.

I've tried doing this

```
    IgniteUtil.getIgnite().compute().affinityRun(IgniteUtil.CACHE_NAME, key , () -> {
        System.out.println("Should only happen once per node");
        List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Size: " + Sets.newHashSet(cache.iterator()).size());
        cache.iterator().forEachRemaining(x -> {count.add(count.size());});
        System.out.println("Calculated Size: " + count.size());
        System.out.println("Values: " );
        cache.get(key).forEach(x -> System.out.print(x));
        System.out.println();
    });
```

and it does only execute on the node that has the key, however, the cache size is the full cache size, not just the values that are local.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast a closure as in your first example and use `IgniteCache.localEntries()` method to iterate through the local data.

Comment: Again, thanks!  One more follow up, if I wanted to do this in a fault tolerant fashion, is there a built in mechanism to do so?  Or would I have to implement something to detect when a node goes down and adjust?

Comment: Yes, you will have to adjust if the topology changes in the middle of execution. You can listen for `EVT_NODE_LEFT` and `EVT_NODE_FAILED` events and react accordingly.